# Reduzir o tamanho de um arquivo APK

Tags: android, apk

É possível reduzir o tamanho de um arquivo APK, alterando a forma como ele é comprimido?

É sabido que um arquivo APK é apenas um arquivo ZIP, assinado e alinhado. Contudo, realizei alguns testes, e se o conteúdo de um arquivo APK for extraído, e então comprimido novamente para um novo arquivo ZIP, seu tamanho diminui ainda mais.

Mas, se renomeio esse arquivo ZIP de volta para APK, o Google Play reclama que o arquivo não está nem assinado, nem alinhado.

Como resolver isso?

*Conheço outras técnicas para reduzir arquivos APK, como utilizar o ProGuard para ofuscar e otimizar o arquivo, remover assets e recursos duplicados, entre outras. O fato é se é mesmo possível diminuir o tamanho final do APK, alterando sua compressão?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, é possível reduzir o tamanho de um arquivo APK, apenas alterando sua compressão.

É possível utilizar qualquer utilitário ZIP, como WinZip, WinRAR, ou o 7-Zip. Eu utilizei o 7-Zip.

Para executar esses comandos, eu criei um script .BAT, mas aqui vou explicando passo-a-passo as linhas do script (meu arquivo APK é `C:\Android\Teste.apk`).

Primeiro me certifico de que a pasta temporária utilizada no processo está vazia, no meu caso `C:\Android\TempAPK`:

```
if exist C:\Android\TempAPK (
del /S /Q C:\Android\TempAPK
rd /S /Q C:\Android\TempAPK
)
md C:\Android\TempAPK
```

Então, extraio o conteúdo do APK para essa pasta temporária:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x C:\Android\Teste.apk -oC:\Android\TempAPK
```

Depois, deve-se excluir a pasta `META-INF`, junto com seu conteúdo (não utilizei o comando `deltree`, porque não o encontrei no Windows 8):

```
del C:\Android\TempAPK\META-INF /S /Q
rd C:\Android\TempAPK\META-INF
```

Em seguida, comprimo os arquivos novamente para um arquivo chamado `Teste.zip` utilizando o método `Deflate` (isso é **OBRIGATÓRIO**), e com as configurações de compressão ao máximo:

```
cd C:\Android
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip C:\Android\Teste.zip .\TempAPK\* -mm=Deflate -mpass=15 -mfb=258
```

Agora é preciso assinar esse ZIP, utilizando a ferramenta `jarsigner`, que vem com o JDK (no meu caso, é o JDK 1.7.0_10):

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin"
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore C:\Android\keystore\keystore.bin -storepass <SENHA DA KEYSTORE> -keypass <SENHA DA KEY> C:\Android\Teste.zip <ALIAS DA KEY>
```

Agora basta alinhar o arquivo ZIP utilizando a ferramenta `zipalign`, criando o APK final, e limpar todos os arquivos temporários (atenção para o caminho do SDK):

```
cd C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W
del C:\Android\Teste.apk
zipalign 4 C:\Android\Teste.zip C:\Android\Teste.apk

del /S /Q C:\Android\TempAPK
rd /S /Q C:\Android\TempAPK
del C:\Android\Teste.zip
```

Isso reduziu o tamanho do meu APK de 330kB para 274kB.

Mais sobre assinatura, no site do Google:

[Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

[Building and Running from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

Comment: Carlos, essa informação é muito boa! Como eu costumo fazer build manualmente, vou tentar portar para Linux e coloco aqui se permitir. +1

Comment: @Wakim com certeza! Ainda não testei o script no Linux! Será genial!!! :D

Comment: Consegui fazer o "port", posso postar como resposta? Tive um ganho de 200kB no processo pra gerar um apk de produção. Num próximo build irei usar essa solução.

Comment: @Wakim Por favor, Wakim!!! Aí vai servir de guia para o pessoal que usa Windows e Linux! \o/

Answer (score 5):

Com a inspiração e trechos da solução do [Rafael](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/7998/carlosrafaelgn), abaixo segue minha adaptação para a plataforma Linux.

**Requisitos:**

1. 7zip, para instalar: `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full`.
2. unzip.
3. jarsigner, localizado na JDK.
4. zipalign, localizado na pasta `build-tools/versao_do_buildtools/zipalign` do SDK do Android.

O script é:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Interrompe o script ao primeiro erro
set -e

# Nome do keystore que ira usar no jarsigner
keystore_name=nome_do_keystore 

# Guardo o nome do usuario corrente
me=$(whoami)

# Variavel que guarda a localizacao do keystore, usado no jarsigner
keystore_location=/home/$me/.android/$keystore_name.jks

# Caminho para o diretorio onde esta o apk
apk_directory=caminho_para_o_seu_apk

# Caminho do apk com o nome
apk_location=$apk_directory/nome_do_seu_apk.apk

# Caminho para o apk final, pronto para producao
apk_location_aligned=$apk_directory/nome_do_seu_apk-release.apk

# Alias name usado na keystore
alias_name=seu_alias_name

echo 'Fazendo a descompressão do apk'

unzip "$apk_location" -d "$apk_directory/apk-uncompressed"

echo 'Apagando o META-INF'

rm -r -f "$apk_directory/apk-uncompressed/META-INF"

echo 'Apagando APK antigo'
rm -f "$apk_location"

echo 'Comprimindo novamente com maior eficiencia'
7z a -tzip "$apk_location" "$apk_directory/*" -mm=Deflate -mpass=15 -mfb=258

echo 'Apagando pasta temporaria'
rm -r -f "$apk_directory/apk-uncompressed"

echo 'iniciando jarsigner'
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "$keystore_location" "$apk_location" "$alias_name"
echo 'jarsigner finalizado'

echo 'iniciando zipalign'
# Corrigir local para o zipalign conforme o necessario
/home/$me/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/20.0.0/zipalign -v 4 "$apk_location" "$apk_location_aligned"
echo 'zipalign finalizado'
```

É preciso fazer algumas adaptações conforme as variáveis que deixei, alguns diretórios podem variar conforme a organização da pessoa e da distribuição Linux (usei o Ubuntu).

Realizei esse processo em meu apk, reduziu o tamanho de **986,5 kB** para **787,0 kB**, um ganho de **199.5kB**. É claro que a redução vai variar de apk para apk, conforme o número de recursos ele usa (xml, png's) e das bibliotecas que você usa.